# Function variables as object field selector

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
populateClinicRoomSelect(object) {
    var selectArray = [];
    var options = [];
    for(var key in object) {
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            options = {
                value: object[key].id,
                label: object[key].RoomName,
            };
            selectArray = selectArray.concat(options);
        }
    }
    return selectArray;
}
```

The idea is that takes two defined fields from the object array and places it in a new array. It works fine. I also have a few more functions exactly the same to this except the 'id' field and 'RoomName' field are different field names. Is there any way to pass 'id' and 'RoomName' as function variables to define them in the function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```js
function populateClinicRoomSelect(object, value, label) {
    value = value || "id"; // defaults value to id
    label = label || "RoomName"; // defaults label to RoomName
    var selectArray = [];
    var options = [];
    for(var key in object) {
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            options = {
                value: object[key][value],
                label: object[key][label],
            };
            selectArray = selectArray.concat(options);
        }
    }
    return selectArray;
}

let obj = { 1: { id:1, RoomName: "Blue Lounge" }, 2: { id:2, RoomName: "Red Lounge" } }

console.log(populateClinicRoomSelect(obj, 'id', 'RoomName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can pass field names as arguments and use `[arg]` accessors as you already do with `[key]`:

```js
function populateClinicRoomSelect(object, valueField, labelField) {
  var selectArray = [];
  var options = [];
  for(var key in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      options = {
        value: object[key][valueField],
        label: object[key][labelField],
      };
      selectArray = selectArray.concat(options);
    }
  }
  return selectArray;
}

const object = {
  a: {
    id: 1,
    room: 'first room'
  },
  b: {
    id: 2,
    room: 'second room'
  }
}

const result = populateClinicRoomSelect(object, 'id', 'room');

console.log(result)
```